# gcc 6.4.0 how to generate EXEC binary on x86_64?

Tags: gcc

Consider `a.c` as containing:

```
void _start(void);
void _start(void) { while (1); }
```

With `gcc 5.4.0` on `Ubuntu`, the following command generates an `ELF` file with type `EXEC` and no external dependencies:

```
gcc -o ./a -x c ./a.c -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs
```

However, the same command with `gcc 6.4.0` on `Gentoo` yields an `ELF` file with type `DYN` that requests the standard program interpreter `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

So, how do I generate a truly standalone `EXEC` binary with `gcc 6.4.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build in non-PIE mode to create a position-dependent executable.  This consists of two steps:

- Compile with `-fno-pie`.
- Link with `-no-pie`.

Linking code compiled as PIE into a position-dependent executable works, but will results in a performance loss and a larger executable.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. One must specify `-no-pie`.